Copy file to overwrite previously archived version: File in Use error
I have a 'Master' Workbook that I copy to an Archive directory. There are instances where I run the routine multiple times a week, therefore, I overwrite (kill) the archived version for that time period with the latest copy.
There are times I get the standard 'File in Use' error. It doesn't say what user, it says 'another user'.
Is my VBA code causing a hung Excel pid or something? Would there be anything in this code that causes my issue?
Sub ClientPrep()

    Dim wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim strPathBin As String
    Dim strSSPath As String
    Dim strTab As String
      
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .AskToUpdateLinks = False
        .AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlManual
    End With
    
    dd = Format(Now, "dd")
    mm = Format(Now, "mm")
    m = Format(Now, "m")
    q = Format(Now, "q")
    yy = Year(Now)

    '''
    Sheets("Results").Activate
    WeekEndDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("F"))
    WeekEndDate = Format(WeekEndDate, "mm-dd-yyyy")
    
    Sheets("Cover Page").Activate
    
    strPathBin = ""
    strSSPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\_Client_Copy\" & WeekEndDate & "\"

    '::-- Set batch variables --::'
    Shell ("cmd.exe /C SETx ClientCopyBin " & "_Client_Copy\" & WeekEndDate & "\")
    Shell ("cmd.exe /C SETx WeekEndDate " & WeekEndDate)

    '::-- Create Archive Directory --::'
    If Dir(strSSPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        Shell ("cmd /c mkdir """ & strSSPath & """")
    End If

    '::-- Copy Files to Archive Directory --::'
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")) 'wait 2 seconds from now

    '::-- Get Client Name --::'
    On Error Resume Next
    strString = Replace(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cover Page").Range("C2"), " ", "_")
    
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
       
    strName = WeekEndDate & "_" & strString & "_Hours_Report.xlsm"
                        
    '::-- Remove Worbook if Exist --::'
    If Dir(strSSPath & strName) <> "" Then Kill strSSPath & strName

    '::-- Make Workbook Copy --::'
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs strSSPath & strName
    
    '::-- Open Client Workbook --::'
    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(strSSPath & strName)

    '::-- Hide Period Tabs if no data exists --::'
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 12
    
        strTab = "P" & i
        
        Sheets(strTab).Cells.Copy
        Sheets(strTab).Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        If i > m Then wbTarget.Worksheets(strTab).Visible = xlSheetHidden
        
        wbTarget.Worksheets(strTab).Range("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Sheets(strTab).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select
    Next
             
    For i = 1 To 4
        
        strTab = "Q" & i
        
        Sheets(strTab).Cells.Copy
        Sheets(strTab).Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                
        If i > q Then wbTarget.Worksheets(strTab).Visible = xlSheetHidden
        
        wbTarget.Worksheets(strTab).Range("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Sheets(strTab).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select
        
    Next i
    
    Sheets("Overage_Tracker").Cells.Copy
    Sheets("Overage_Tracker").Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select
                 
    '::-- Clear Results Tab --::'
    wbTarget.Worksheets("Results").Cells.Clear

    
    '::-- Hide Sheets --::'
    On Error Resume Next
    wbTarget.Worksheets("Contract").Visible = xlSheetHidden
    wbTarget.Worksheets("Results").Visible = xlSheetHidden
    wbTarget.Worksheets("Overage_Tracker").Visible = xlSheetHidden
    wbTarget.Worksheets("Instructions").Visible = xlSheetHidden
    wbTarget.Worksheets("Task").Visible = xlSheetHidden
    wbTarget.Worksheets("Rate_Card").Visible = xlSheetHidden
    wbTarget.Worksheets("Non-Standard_Tracker").Visible = xlSheetHidden
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    wbTarget.Worksheets("Cover Page").Activate
    wbTarget.Save: wbTarget.Close
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Cover Page").Activate
    
End Sub


For the avoidance of doubt, exactly which line does the error occur on?

It happens on this line ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs strSSPath & strName
It seems the kill command before that isn't killing?

If you can reproduce the problem on demand, or at least fairly reliably, maybe putting Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")) on the line after the Kill would give enough time for whatever (e.g., antivirus maybe) is looking at the file time to release it.

If Dir(strSSPath & strName) <> "" Then Kill strSSPath & strName Put a breakpoint and check if the line is executing. You may also want to put DoEvents after that line so that you give ample amount for the deletion to happen.

Building onto Siddharth, in the past I have used Do Until IsError(Evaluate()) to ensure the specific workbook has closed; there are other options, but that is one that has been successful for me.

Thanks all! So upon doing more testing, I was mistaken.  THe error occurs on this line Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(strSSPath & strName)
So what's odd to me is why would the SaveAs work then? I would expect the SaveAs to fail and cause an error. Either way, it still seems like the kill is the problem. I did put a wait in the code, and still same issue.

Okay so I have more details, and in retrospect, I should have shared earlier. I'm able to reproduce the error regularly, but some methods do not yield an error.
When scheduled, it's a Powershell script that calls my Master Workbook, which then that Master Workbook creates the Archive Copy.  If I have the Archive Copy OPEN, I am able to reproduce the error.
However, if I have the Archive Copy open and just trigger the Routine through the Master Workbook, it works as expected.  How come calling via PowerShell would have different results?

I'm guessing that powershell uses a different/separate instance of Excel to the one you are working with.

That makes sense. So Powershell is using one session, but my Master Workbook is spawning a new instance when it goes to make the Archive Copy.  Is there a way around this?

So interestingly enough, when I reproduce the error, even with the following piece of code (just before the open command) Workbooks(strSSPath & strName).Close SaveChanges:=False the file I manually opened to reproduce the error doesn't actually close... Is this expected? While seperate excel instances (as CDP1802 said above), wouldn't it still recognize it as open and close it?

Try with On Error Goto 0 before the close. Why On Error Resume Next under get client name ?

But the error is happening on the opening command after the save-as. What would adding On Error Goto 0 before the close accomplish?
I was also thinking do I need a wbTarget = Nothing as well?

I'm trying to understand your code, what is Sheets(strTab).Cells.Copy :        Sheets(strTab).Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues for ( I guess its removing formulas) . It's applied to the master and not the archive copy, is this correct ? What do you want to happen if powershell encounted the archive file open, abort ?

Yes that is correct, but it's applied to the Archive copy. Essentially, the Archive Workbook is the same as the Master, but I want to remove formulas.
And I want the "open" Archive Workbook to get CLOSED if it encounters it so it can continue processes and finishes the routine.

Would I have to add code to Powershell? Because technically, Powershell isn't opening the Archive copy, it's the Master.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

As you mentioned you are running multiple instances and this error occur when the file is still opened in one of them.
A workaround in case you know which file has the error is to open it again:
Workbooks.Open(filePath)

Good luck!
